# QtCreator : Why can i create a project in C, but can't create a .c file to add to the project?

Tags: c, header, include, qt-creator

In QtCreator when i create my project in C, the main file is .c but i can't create other C file to implement my .h, i just can create .cpp file.
Someone knows how to create a .c file and add to my project in QtCreator?

Answer (score 2):

Select `File -> New File or Project`, then from `Files and Classes` list select `General`. Then select `Text File`, press `Choose...` and give the file name with the extension you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.c` files the same way as you create `.cpp` files. You just need to write extension `.c` in the dialog.

(`File -> New File or Project`, `C++` in `Files and Classes`, `C++ Source File`, `Choose...`, paste name with extension `blah.c`)